# How to deal with cross-elasticity and time series for optimal pricing with causal inference?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, causality, granger-causality

I have a problem in which the prices of an "item" will change for specific hours of the day. I was leveraging the concept of price elasticity, which includes the self- and cross-elasticity coefficients (which are not directly observed), to evaluate the impact of that change.

As there are can be other factors that affect the purchasing of this item (temperature, hour of the day, precipitation, ...), I was trying to build a model based on causal inference techniques, so that the effect of price on demand is properly captured. I am dealing with a time series: I have pre-treatment data for some months (no price changes during the day), and the treatment data generation for the next months will depend on how I set the prices during the day. I cannot make a random trial, in which the treatment would only be given to certain random customers, due to business reasons.

As I wanted these prices to be changed optimally (e.g., in the most favorable hours to maximize profits), I was hoping to use a causal model within an optimization problem, in which the causal model would be retrained periodically, as more data becomes available. There are example of using, for example, ML models within causal inference, even within the context of price elasticity of demand (e.g., https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/20-Plug-and-Play-Estimators.html)

However, I have not found examples that deal with causal inference within time-series and cross-elasticity concerns. The cross-elasticity is critical, as in this setting customers can purchase this "item" in different hours due to the change in price in another hour. Within this context, do you know any examples/techniques that may be helpful? Do you know if any available package for causal inference (e.g., EconML, CausalML, DoWhy, DoubleML) would already account for this somehow (e.g., should I just use prices in different hours as a feature for a ML model that can be used in one of those packages?)

Thank you.

I tried analyzing the different packages available for causal inference, but no similar examples were found. There also tutorial on causal inference that deal with price elasticity of demand (e.g, https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/20-Plug-and-Play-Estimators.html) but do not account for cross-elasticity.

Comment: You are aware that *causal inference within time-series and cross-elasticity models* are a class of models known as panel data analysis in economics and pooled time series in other disciplines such as marketing science. In 1988, Cooper and Nakanishi wrote an excellent book, * Market-Share Analysis*, on applying these models with explicit focus on generating cross-elasticities. Forget the 'market share' part, it's just an excellent approach which remains timely. Browse the ToC for relevant topics https://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty/lee.cooper/MCI_Book/BOOKI2010.pdf